# How to remove user claims in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, claims

i am working in a simple asp.net mvc5 app and i am very new to claim concept , can anyone help me how to achieve this thing , i have listed all the app users and their related custom claims in a table , near every claim i have placed a link (x sign) which means to delete that claim , how can i achieve that , i mean when i click that 'x' sign to delete that corresponding user's claim from AspNetUserClaims table in database .When every user is created (registred into app -register action) two claims are created by default with it, please refer to the question detailed link 
https://forums.asp.net/p/2133652/6183225.aspx?p=True&t=636494239089038616

Comment: I would recommend you include a [mcve] in your question, rather than a link to an external website.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can remove claim from a user by using this code :

```
_userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(User, Claim);
```

If you want to get user's claims use this :

```
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
```

Comment: where to put that please ? check the last reply i did here https://forums.asp.net/p/2133652/6183429.aspx?p=True&t=636494269203237318

Comment: .Net has it's own Claim model, Why you're making a new claims model!?

Comment: okay can you please tell me how to achieve that , i said i am very very new to claims sorry

Comment: Check this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims

Because I can't explain the whole concept in a comment.

Comment: @SaadAli  Well you could update your answer, such as how do you find the individual claim you want to remove? (it's kind of missing that bit).